# PHPPowerpoint live object Issue

Tags: php, powerpoint-2007

I am using phppowerpoint from codeplex, that is work fine at local xampp server but when i have do live that then show phppowerpoint class is not found plese help me

Comment: What is the error in Production Server?

Comment: How can check Production Server error

Comment: Check the `error log` file from production server to see the actual error.